# C++ showing caught exception in MessageDialog

Tags: win-universal-app, c++-cx, messagedialog

I’m currently learning C++/CX, with Windows Universal App, and I want to show a caught exception message in a `MessageDialog`, however, C++/CX works in a way that I don’t understand, in that I can't convert a `char*` into a `string` type, which is what the `MessageDialog` expects as input.

```
catch (const std::invalid_argument ex)
{
   MessageDialog^ ErrorBox = ref new MessageDialog(ex.what());
   ErrorBox->ShowAsync();
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: I don't recall the character ^ after MessageDialog being valid in that context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MessageDialog` accepts a `Platform::String`.

The `Platform::String` accepts a `char16* s`

And you have a `char*`, so, you have to find a way to convert it to `char16*`, and this is how you do it:

```
wchar_t buffer[ MAX_BUFFER ];
mbstowcs( buffer, ex.what(), MAX_BUFFER );
platformString = ref new Platform::String( buffer );
```

This should work:

```
catch (const std::invalid_argument ex)
{
   wchar_t buffer[ MAX_BUFFER ];
   mbstowcs( buffer, ex.what(), MAX_BUFFER );
   platformString = ref new Platform::String( buffer );
   MessageDialog^ ErrorBox = ref new MessageDialog(platformString);
   ErrorBox->ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

I had to change it a bit though, i thought MAX_BUFFER was a part of a library, but i couldnt make it work, so i gave it an integer instead.

And instead of mbstowcs, i had to use mbstowcs_s, as the compiler complained that the former was insecure.

Again, thanks :)